# Fastest way to parse log to find each user's all source IPs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, logging, text-parsing

I have huge of logs like:

```
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.X:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userA 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.X:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userA 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.X:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userB 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.X:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userC 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.X:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userC 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.X:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userD 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
```

Which is the fastest way in Bash shell to parse the log to out like(each user's all request souce IPs):

```
userA:
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX(client's source IP, remove port number and uniq same IPs.)
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
...
userB:
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
...
userC:
...
```

Comment: I tried stupid and slow method, it's skill-less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use awk:

```
awk '
{ a[$6] = $4 "\n" a[$6] }                                     
END {
    for (u in a) print u ":\n" a[u]
}' FILE
```

To remove ports and uniq hosts try this (I didn't test this well):

```
awk '
{
  sub(":.*$", "", $4)
  if (!a[$6,$4]) a[$6,$4]++
}
END {
    for (u in a ) {
      split(u, b, SUBSEP)
      nu[b[1]] = b[2] "\n" nu[b[1]]
   }
   for (u in nu) print u ":\n" nu[u]
}' FILE
```

Comment: Cool method. Another relate question, in awk here, how to remove IP's port like 11.250.30.X:53516 -> 11.250.30.X and uniq the same IPs? Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the AWK program keeps all the data in memory. if your log is really big, it might run very slow. In this case you can run a AWK that just prints user and IP, then sort by user, and run second AWK that print every time the user changes, and for each line, prints the IP.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful; it gets the desired data (a list of user/ip pairs sorted by user) in a form suitable for further automatic processing:

```
awk '{split($4,a,":"); print $6, a[1]; }' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

A Bash solution:

```
declare -A ips=()
while read x x x ip x user rest; do
  ips[$user ${ip%:*}\\n]=1                  # hash user+ip+newline
done < "$infile"

userold=''
while read user ip; do                      # split user, ip
  [ "$userold" != "$user" ] && echo "$user" && userold="$user"
  echo  "$ip"
done < <( echo -e "${!ips[*]}" | sort )     # feed sorted keys
```

The input:

```
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.1:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userA 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:54  11.250.30.2:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userA 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:55  11.250.30.3:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userB 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:51  11.250.30.4:53516 [15/Apr /2012:06:24:51.504] userC 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:52  11.250.30.4:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userC 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
Apr 15 06:24:58  11.250.30.5:53516 [15/Apr/2012:06:24:51.504] userD 200 "GET HTTP/1.1"
```

The output is sorted:

```
userA
11.250.30.1
11.250.30.2
userB
11.250.30.3
userC
11.250.30.4
userD
11.250.30.5
```